# The REST API request failed due to an error. cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: ssl

I am seeing the error cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired  in the site health check and I also get it when saving some pages or trying to update plugins.

However my website is working fine,  ( https link works and shows the lock)

Additionally I tried solution in other similar questions like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107431/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-certificate-has-expired

I checked in particular https://whatsmychaincert.com which indicates certificate should be ok.

And my server clearly shows that the certificate is up to date.  Site has been working for about a year without issues.  Are there some other steps to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found that  recently (Sept 30) the Let's Encrypt Cretificates expired DST Root CA X3. In addition to the curl error 60 I also had Rest API errors and inability to updated plugins in wordpress.   It is possible to update these in the wordpress installation:

The patch is available here  and should be available with Wordpress 5.9 (December 2021) if not earlier:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/51883/trunk/src/wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt